# Loading Raw JSON Into Delta Lake (Like in Snowflake)

Tags: json, pyspark, delta-lake

I am testing Delta Lake for a simple use case that is very easy in Snowflake, but I'm having a heck of a time understanding *if* it can be done, much less actually doing it.

I want to be able to load a JSON file "raw," without specifying a schema, and I want to be able to query and flatten it later. In Snowflake, I can create a column of type VARIANT and load the JSON text there, and later I can ask for the different parts by using `::` and `lateral flatten`, etc.

The examples I've seen so far about Delta Lake have had "schema inference" or "autoloading" stipulations, and with those it seems that even if I don't specify a schema, one is created for me and then I still have to guess (or look up) what columns Delta Lake created for me so I can query those parts of the JSON. It seems a little too complicated.

[This page](https://databricks.com/blog/2021/11/11/10-powerful-features-to-simplify-semi-structured-data-management-in-the-databricks-lakehouse.html) has the following comment:

> When ingesting data, you may need to keep it in a JSON string, and some data may not be in the correct data type.

... but it provides no example of how to do that. To me this suggests that you *can* somehow store the raw JSON and query it later, but I don't know how. Just make a STRING column and insert the JSON as string? Can someone post an example?

Am I trialing the wrong tool for what I need, or am I missing something? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you using Databricks or just OSS Delta?

Comment: Just the "plain" Delta Lake, I brought it up in a Docker container by installing on top of Ubuntu, I got the [quickstart](https://docs.delta.io/latest/quick-start.html) to work with pyspark, etc., where I basically have a Python interpreter to run the commands into.

Comment: Any updates? I have the same issue, and I keep getting errors about duplicate columns, but I don't know how to deal with them!

Comment: OP here, just wanted to add that we decided we were indeed trialing the wrong tool, we went with PostgreSQL w/ the Citus plugin for scalability, etc. Not exactly an "answer," but since this was proof-of-concept, maybe my story will help someone else's decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there is no direct equivalent to the `VARIANT` column in Snowflake. What that page is suggesting is storing the data as a string, and then using the semi-structured access operators to parse it as JSON on the fly.

e.g. given a table named `devices` with a column named `specifications` of type `string` with value

```
"""{
  "device": "potato phone",
  "sku": "POTATO0001",
}"""
```

Then you can query it like this:

```
SELECT specifications:device, specifications:sku from devices
```

edit: to address some of your other questions

This doesn't do schema enforcement. It's possible to create a `Struct` column in delta lake that can store structured data, but all the data in that column need to be compatible with the `Struct` schema. If you are querying a JSON string column, you are on your own for schema management.